# Android ID showing up in Outlook web access

Tags: android, activesync, outlook-web-app

I have an HTC incredible synced with my OWA.
In OWA when I go to Options -> Mobile Devices, I see in the status column some device ID starting with HTCAnd followed by a 8 character hex number.

None of the API's I used on android gave me this ID. Is this some ID that is encrypted by Active Sync ? How do I co-relate this ID with my device (in case of multiple devices) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's an ID passed by the device in each ActiveSync HTTPS request. If your phone doesn't have a way of displaying that ID, the easiest way to figure out which code belongs to which phone is to first turn off all the phones, then  use the OWA interface to remove the mobile devices (don't worry, they'll still be able to re-sync automatically) and then turn them on one by one. As you turn them on and they sync you'll see them appear in the OWA mobile devices page, allowing you to match the ID to the device.

Comment: Thanks Brian. However, I was looking for a way for an enterprise admin to find this out for their users. This will not be a practical approach for such kind of situation !

Comment: Ah, understood. Well, I would suggest looking into the HTC docs to see if there's a way to determine the ID directly from the device instead.